# Add text after a specific amount of words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been working on this issue for weeks with no luck. So I thought I would ask for some help. I have a word document that has a term Data Flow Task on it. I am documenting dtsx packages. So in this case I have 35 Data Flow Tasks, which I automatically populate the sheet with the titles Data Flow Task: and Container Name. Since the Data Flow Tasks are the same name I would like to populate them automatically. My current code just populates the last Data Flow Task and that's it. I am getting no errors , but the code isn't doing what I need it to. I started off using the range object but it wouldn't count the next loop. Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Sub AddDataFlowTaskName()
Dim curDoc As Document
Dim strFindTaskTitle As String
Dim strAddTaskName As String
Dim lTotalCount As Long
Dim lSubTotal As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim s1 As Long
Dim e1 As Long

Set curDoc = ActiveDocument

    strFindTaskTitle = "Data Flow Task:"
   'strAddTaskName = InputBox("Enter Task Name")
   'lTotalCount = InputBox("Enter Total Amount of Tasks")
   'lSubTotal = InputBox("Enter Amount of Subtasks")
    strAddTaskName = "DF STEP 1 Kick"
    lTotalCount = 35
    lSubTotal = 3

For x = 1 To lTotalCount
    For y = 1 To lSubTotal
         With curDoc.Range.Find
              .Forward = True
              .Text = strFindTaskTitle
              .Execute FindText:=strFindTaskTitle
              curDoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:=strAddTaskName
         End With
     Next y
   Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't at all apparent why you're not using a simple Find/Replace without all the looping. See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/160315-post9.html and, for multiple terms: https://www.msofficeforums.com/147418-post3.html. See also https://www.msofficeforums.com/131538-post2.html & https://www.msofficeforums.com/118954-post2.html

Comment: I tried to do the simple Find/replace, that doesn't work because I am trying to add a specific number of data flow tasks, the first loop would be to change 5 data flow tasks, then the second loop would change 3, third loop change 2 and so on. So I don't want to change all the Data Flow Tasks with the same name.

Comment: In that case, you need to update your initial post to describe exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. Neither your description nor your code gives any hint of that. Moreover, If you have 'Data Flow Tasks' that need to be changed to different things, what do they need to be changed to and why are they all named the same?